# How can I stop my sprite from jolting up in air in SFML?

Tags: c++, 2d, game-physics, sfml

How can I stop my sprite from suddenly jolting up in air when I press jump?

My code:

```
sf::Vector2f velocity, position;
const float speed,gravity,jumpSpeed;
bool groundCollision,jumping;

if (!groundCollision) {
    isJumping = true;
    velocity.y += gravity;
} else {
    isJumping = false;
}
if (!isJumping && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space)) {
    velocity.y -= jumpSpeed;
}
```

I want my sprite to jump up and come down smoothly when I press jump now it suddenly jolts up but comes back down smoothly.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. It's almost impossible to tell what's wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In this part, shouldn't you use gravity instead of jumpspeed?

```
if (!isJumping && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space))
{
    //velocity.y -= jumpSpeed * deltaTime.asSeconds();
    //              ^ should this jumpSpeed be gravity?
    velocity.y = jumpSpeed;
    velocity.y -=  gravity * deltaTime.asSeconds();
}
```

Comment: No, the jumpSpeed is for jumping and gravity is applied if the sprite is not colliding with the ground anymore.